# Proper use of ViewModel with editing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm still trying to learn MVC and now that I'm implementing it in a real world site I'm coming up with more questions. My current issue is about how I would use a ViewModel to get data for an edit.

The scenario is that I have Member page to let the user change their Name, Address, Phone, etc. I have the basic information about someone in a table called Person and their address information in Address. So, I created a ViewModel that basically combines both of them to pass to the View.

As far as I can tell I have to create an object of both tables and then combine them manually into a ViewModel before sending to the View. This seems a little cumbersome and I feel like their is probably a better way to do this. When I search online I can seem to find anything that covers this. Everything I find is a simple example where someone basically maps a ViewModel directly from a table.

Here is what I've basically come up with. Am I going down the right path or is there a better way to do this?

```
Person currentPerson = db.Person.Find(id);
Address currentAddress = db.Address.Find(currentPerson.PID);

MemberViewModel currentUser = new MemberViewModel();
currentUser.FirstName = currentPerson.FirstName;
currentUser.LastName = currentPerson.LastName;
currentUser.MemberId = currentPerson.PID;
currentUser.Address = currentAddress.Address1;
currentUser.City = currentAddress.City;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach. But there are tools such as [automapper](http://automapper.org/) which make mapping between your data models and view models a little easier

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one good reasons why you need to use ViewModel which is pretty similar to DB model.

1. Most often business objects come from Entity framework db objects if you are using entity framework. In MVC we use data attribute validations such as required validation etc. (System.ComponentModel). But if we use these validations in Entityframework generated classes, and if we change the db and refresh the class, those custom attributes will be lost.
2. If you are using WCF or web services, custom ViewModel classes are light weight to transfer because DB objects have things like relationships to other objects.
3. ViewModel classes gives the option to combine objects and have custom fields. 
   Relating to the Users, one good example is that user login. Usually it involves username, password and remember me check box. "Remember Me" is not a field that is stored in db. But to pass that value from View to Controller we can use an object like LoginUserViewModel which has username, password and remember me.

Of course, there is a object mapping involved when retrieving and saving data. Automapper is the tool for that.

Comment: I read a little about Automapper during my searching but wasn't sure if that is what others are typically using or if manual mapping was what is more of the standard.

Comment: If you are dealing with complex objects (invoices, payments etc.) manual conversion is error prone and it creates noisy code. Automapper helps to keep the code base clean and do conversions. I love it. I'm not sure about standard, but I have been using Automapper for last 2 years in different projects which worked really well for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to look into Automapper. If you have any articles that you know of that will point me into how to use Automapper, please pass them along. In the meantime I'll search through Google and maybe YouTube to see if I can find something.

Comment: It's pretty straight forward to use. Refer to https://dotnetcademy.net/Learn/2/Pages/2 for a quick start. When you try to convert composite objects you need to create mappers for child classes. Nothing much to learn though, just start with your example. Only thing is that you need to have a discipline with naming class fields (if you use the same naming and variable types there's nothing to worry about). Give it a try!

Comment: I started another question specifically for Automapper. See if you have any suggestions for me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804073/not-able-to-add-second-entity-to-viewmodel-with-automapper?noredirect=1#comment57351167_34804073