# Not able to add second entity to ViewModel with Automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm still learning MVC and I'm was just recently suggested to look at using AutoMapper to map my ViewModel. So, I started a test but I'm not understanding how to map two entities nor can I find an example.

What I have is a Person table and an Address table. I want to combine the two into a ViewModel to pass to my View. Looking at examples they always show how to map one entity but not two.

In the following code I can see that both my currentPerson and currentAddress objects are populated with data using the debugger but then my currentMember ViewModel only has the Person data. That makes sense because I'm only using Mapper.Map on the Person but how do I tell the currentMember to map the Address as well?

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
            {
                Person currentPerson = db.Person.Find(id);
                Address currentAddress = db.Address.Single(a => a.PID == id);

                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, AdminViewModel>();
                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AdminViewModel>();

                MemberViewModel currentMember = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<AdminViewModel>(currentPerson);

                return View(currentMember);
            }
        }
```

Comment: how about you create two properties in `AdminViewModel` and then map them individually ?

Comment: That's what I was doing initially and that's when it was suggested to me to use Automapper to not have to manually map properties.

Comment: yes and to be honest thats the way i am doing all the time. When you map them individually, assign them manually to view model

Comment: Does person has a navigation property to Address? It would make more sense loading them in on call. With that, you can map both with AutoMapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AutoMapper.Map` has an overload that takes a source and destination object. So you can take advantage of it using something like this:

**Create ViewModels**

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    //your person fields here..
    //create them with the same name as Person 
    //to avoid having to set each field during mapping  
}

public class AddressViewModel
{
    //your address fields here..
}

public class AdminViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel Person {get; set;}   

    public AddressViewModel Address {get; set;} 
}
```

**Crete the mappings** (You should centralize all your mappings in a class):

```
public class EntityToViewModelProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        //Create mappings for Person and Address
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, AdminViewModel>();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AdminViewModel>();


        //Create a map to AdminViewModel for both Person and Address

        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Person, Models.AdminViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Person, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Address, Models.AdminViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
    }
}
```

Register EntityToViewModelProfile in `Global.asax.cs`

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.AddProfile<EntityToViewModelProfile>();
});
```

Then, in your controller you use the overload of `.Map`

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    Person currentPerson = db.Person.Find(id);
    Address currentAddress = db.Address.Single(a => a.PID == id);

    var mapPerson = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Person, AdminViewModel>(currentPerson);

    var mapPersonAndAddress = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Address, AdminViewModel>(currentAddress, mapPerson);

    return View(mapPersonAndAddress);
}
```

Comment: what is `destination2`?

Comment: @jpgrassi, in the "Create the mappings", what is the .ForMember used for? From the examples I saw it looked like you use the ForMember to assign two values to a parameter (ex: DisplayName = FristName + LastName). If I'm mapping properties one to one do I still need the .ForMember?

Comment: @Caverman, yes you are correct. I had the same question. You probably just need to create two simple mappings one for person and other for address, but I haven't test that.  I just leave that you so you can understand clearly what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Jpgrassi looks good and it's pretty cool way to convert. But If you are doing the conversions in a DB or BL layer (rather than the Controller itself), keeping your conversions to Business Objects to BOViewModel (Person to PersonViewModel etc.) in a is more reusable. More often you need a separate project which defines your BOViewModels (Something like MyProject.BO)

I would rather follow the simple and straightforward approach to create the AdminViewModel,

```
var personViewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();
var addressViewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel>();
```

These conversions are useful to convert DB objects to BO, which would ideally takes place in a DB or BL layer. Then pass the personViewModel and addressViewModel to Controller and create the AdminViewModel in the controller.

This is simple and this pattern works across the service boundaries or applications with many layers.

Comment: At the moment this I'm just looking to do this in the controller but I do have intentions to come back and refactor the code some more once I get my head wrapped around it all a little more. I would like to have a central location like a Business layer that would do all of this for me because I can see where I would need to create a MemberViewModel in a handful of places. Things like display of the Member, a MyAccount section, and a Admin section to edit them. I would prefer to maintain this code in one place and not do the same thing in multiple controllers.

Comment: Sounds good! try to reuse as much as possible. If you keep components simple this will happen automatically.